# Getting data from another table for web

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, merge, html-table

I'm trying to make a table of "bans" for my server. It works, but I just don't know how to replace `player_id` with `player_name` from another table. Also, I'm not a developer, which should give away from the title.

The table for this is `adkats_bans`, which gets the player ID from from table called `tbl_playerdata`

Here is what I have so far:

```
   <?php
mysql_select_db($database);
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT player_id,ban_startTime,ban_endTime,ban_notes FROM adkats_bans ORDER by player_id;");

$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rank))
{
if($row['ban_notes']== 'NoNotes'){
    $reason="Auto banned.";
}
    echo '
<td>'.$i.'</td>
<td><div align="center">'.$row['player_id'].'</td>
<td><div align="center">'.$row['ban_startTime'].'</td>
<td><div align="center">'.$row['ban_endTime'].'</td>
<td><div align="center">'.$reason.'</td>
</tr> ';
$i=$i+1;
}


?>
</tr></table>
```

So for names, their `player_id` shows. I could just edit and paste it under this for `player_id` = `player_name` sort of table, but it's not professional.

If you can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your structure correctly this `INNER JOIN` should get the data you want

```
SELECT 
  ab.player_id,
  pd.player_name
  ab.ban_startTime,
  ab.ban_endTime,
  ab.ban_notes 
FROM 
  adkats_bans AS ab
INNER JOIN
  tbl_playerdata AS pd ON ab.player_id = pd.player_id
ORDER BY 
  ab.player_id ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed `ab.` and `pd.` and it worked.